# Xml Document, escape this character

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encoding, xmldocument

I have an XML document that has the paragraph separator character in some nodes as

When I load XML into an `XmlDocument` object, I no longer see this character. Instead I see a space. How do I get it to show  ?

---

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFilePath); 
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/catalog/classes"); 
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes) { 
    string category = node["category"]; 
    bool containerSeperator = category.Contains("&#x2029;") // this should return true but it returns false. This category has a paragraph separator
}
```

Comment: I cannot change the source xml documents.

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(xmlFilePath);
XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/catalog/classes");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string category = node["category"];
    bool containerSeperator = category.Contains("&#x2029;") // this should return true but it returns false. This category has a paragraph seperator
}

Comment: you can edit your question to post code.

Answer (score 0):

Test #1:

```
var xmlText = @"<Test>&amp;</Test>";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
var result = xml.Element("Test").Value;
```

`result` will not be `&amp;`, result will be `"`. So `Contains("&amp;")` will never be true.

Test #2:

```
var xmlText = @"<Test>&#x2029;</Test>";
var xml = XDocument.Parse(xmlText);
var result = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(xml.Element("Test").Value);
```

result will be two bytes: `x20` and `x29`, which is exactly what is read from XML. So the bytes are there you just don't see them as this Unicode character is not readable.

Comment: XmlNodeList nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/catalog/classes");
foreach(XmlNode node in nodes)
{
   Console.Writeline(node["class_name"] + node["category"])
}

how can I do the same using xdocument? I tried using XPathSelectElements but it returns a list of xmlelement?